# MongoDB refuses connection unless I am using Compass, or MongoDB Shell

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I've just installed mongodb and I am able to interact with my collections via the Compass app, and the Mongodb Shell, however, When I try to use the VScode extension to connect to the DB, or I try to interact with my DB with mongoose, I get a connection refused error.

```
localhost:27017' => ServerDescription {
        address: 'localhost:27017',
        type: 'Unknown',
        hosts: [],
        passives: [],
        arbiters: [],
        tags: {},
        minWireVersion: 0,
        maxWireVersion: 0,
        roundTripTime: -1,
        lastUpdateTime: 3135642,
        lastWriteDate: 0,
        error: MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
            at connectionFailureError (/home/dirtykeyboard/Development/code/testing/mongo-express/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connect.js:370:20)
            at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/dirtykeyboard/Development/code/testing/mongo-express/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connect.js:293:22)
            at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
            at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
            at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:157:8)
            at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:122:3)
            at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
          cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
              at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1247:16) {
            errno: -111,
            code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
            syscall: 'connect',
            address: '127.0.0.1',
            port: 27017
          }
```

[image: VSCode Extension Error]

[image: Mongosh]

Here is my collection from the shell, and compass:

[image: Shell]

[image: Compass]

So far I have reinstalled and tried to re run mongod after creating the db file in C:/data

Answer (score 0):

The 'data' folder should not be created there. Instead, create it as  C:\Program Files\MongoDB\data\db.

Using cmd, start MongoDB service by using command 'mongod'

Then try to connect, that fixed it for me. Hopefully that works for you too.

Edit: Restarting your computer after might also help